# Is there a tool to check my math in latex?

Tags: math-mode

Is there any tool that can warn me if my equations in latex seem wrong? For example, when I used a wrong sign, or when my arithmetic is incorrect. I don't need a complete verifier. Something that will highlight the most obvious mathematical mistakes that I make is enough. I don't mind some false-positive and false-negative results. I know that there are such proof checkers as coq, but these things are too complex, and are overkill for my tasks.

Comment: For easy expressions it can be done with LuaTeX. Could you give some examples of expressions to check?

Comment: While this seems, in principle, a nice thing to have, it doesn't exist. Moreover, it will most likely require far more investment to even come close to useful - in general - than an answer here can offer. As an example, how would this system verify `\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}`? It would be easier to compile your document and ask a friend to verify your work.

Comment: @Werner I see 3 options, how such a system could work: 1. using machine learning, 2. using numerical tests with a few random numbers, 3. using symbolic rules and set of known formulas.

Comment: I think that the better strategy is using a CAS like `maxima` for this. You "make" formulas with the CAS, and then you ask the CAS to translate them in LaTeX. I do not think that a after-the-fact check is even possible.

Comment: @TeXnician If such tool could highlight even simplest cases like -(a+b)^2  = -a^2+2ab+b^2, or 42/6 = 8 I'd already be happy. Here are some formulas from my homework that I'm currently doing https://ibb.co/fX6xdyz , in case you're curious.

Comment: @Arqwer: For purely numeric/computational things, you can use LaTeX. For example, `\usepackage{xfp}` allows you to write `$42 / 6 = \inteval{42 / 6}$` rather than `$42 / 6 = 7$`. Algebraic equations (in general) would be a far reach...

Comment: The most reliable tool is your head: you have to learn to proofread.

Comment: it would be very difficult even to extract the math even before you try to find a system to evaluate it, you would have to parse past variable and incorrect markup, just the output in your link for example shows `max` being rendered inconsistently even within the same denominator both (correct) roman, possibly from `\max` and (incorrect) math italic from `\sum^{max}` (I would guess) normalizing such variable input to get something to pass to a proof checker is almost as hard as the checking itself.